# Check if request to api is made from frontend or backend application

Tags: security

In order to restrict actions to specific tokens I need to check if a request made to my api is made from an frontend or backend application.

I want to implement the same behavior like Stripe. Using a secret key on client side will result in an error.

So is there a safe way to check this?

Answer (score 0):

The answer could be through the User Agent, but in fact there is no exact way to identify and differentiate whether a request came from a browser or from another API for example, as it is possible to manipulate the User Agent.

Well-behaved "bots" (like common search engine spiders) will identify themselves using a User Agent specific to them.